# Positional arguments with embedpy on KDB

Tags: kdb

```
\l p.q

np:.p.import`numpy
Logistic:.p.import[`sklearn.linear_model;`:LogisticRegression]

train_X_np: np[`:array](1 2 3)
train_Y_np: np[`:array](0 1 1)

Logistic[`:fit][train_X_np;train_Y_np]
```

When I run this I get:

```
call: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

What am I doing wrong?

(Also normally, there should be a `.reshape(-1,1)` on the `X` array, I wonder if this is the cause?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to initialise the LogisticRegression object
- You need to reshape the x input

  ```
  q)Logistic:.p.import[`sklearn.linear_model;`:LogisticRegression][]
  q)train_X_np: np[`:array][1 2 3][`:reshape;-1 1]
  q)Logistic[`:fit][train_X_np;train_Y_np]
  / To predict
  q)Logistic[`:predict][np[`:array][0 1 2][`:reshape;-1 1]]`
  0 1 1
  ```

You could also use `flip enlist 1 2 3` kdb list before passing it to numpy instead of reshaping